# Remove OS from server and return to PXE boot

Tags: pxe-boot, restore

I installed Ubuntu 18.04.4 on my HP DL360 G10 servers.  When they were initially installed, they were trying to PXE boot from the different network adapters.  Now that I've installed an OS on them, they boot directly from the hard disk.  I would like to return them to the original state, erasing the installed OS, and allowing them to boot from the network until a new OS is served via PXE.  Is there a general procedure for this activity?  I haven't found anything concrete yet.

Comment: Choosing the boot mode is the goal of a "BIOS". Look for a boot sequence or something like it. Perhaps if you disable the Ubuntu boot disk (disconnecting sATA wire), the system may automaticaly start PXE (because it is stil the second in the boot queue).

Comment: Thanks schweik.  I was wondering about something like that, but then I want the server to start using whatever OS is pushed via PXE.  So the server needs to be able to install the OS via PXE and start using the OS after it is installed, ideally without any further changes by me to BIOS/UEFI.

Comment: Is it using EFI or pcbios?
You can see almost identical question: https://serverfault.com/questions/1021965/wipe-linux-system-remotely-to-make-it-unbootable